# Regular Expression to Match Number of Lines and Characters per Line

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I'm trying to make sure that a string contains between 0 and 3 lines, and that for a given line that is present that it contains 0 to 100 characters. It would need to be a valid expression for JavaScript and Java. Like many people doing RegEx I'm copying from various spots on the Internet.

Working backwards I think `^.{0,100}$` gets me the "line contains 0 to 100 characters", but trying to group that as `(^.{0,100}$){0,3}` doesn't work.

The new line character is probably part of my problem, so I ended up with something like `.{0,100}(?:\n.{0,100}){0,2}` trying to say "a line of 0 to 100 characters optionally followed by 0 to 2 instances of a new line and 0 to 100 more characters", but that also failed.

Up until now I got those expressions from other people. Using an online test tool I finally monkeyed this together: `^.{0,100}(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).{0,100}){0,2}$` which appears to work.

So, my question is, am I missing any pitfalls in `^.{0,100}(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).{0,100}){0,2}$` given what I'm after? Furthermore, even if that does work is it the best expression to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you have will work fine. You can make the line break part a little more compact if you want, and you don't need `^` and `$` if you are using `matches()`:

```
String regex = ".{0,100}(?:[\r\n]+.{0,100}){0,2}";
```

**EDIT**

After some more thoughts I realized the newline suggestion above will match 4 (or more) lines as long as a couple of them are empty. So, we are back to your suggested example. Oh well, at least the start and end characters can be omitted.

```
String regex = ".{0,100}(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).{0,100}){0,2}";
```

Comment: i agree with you that i can drop them, but my caveat is that i can only configue one string. the sdk i'm using will then generate JS as well as java code using the same pattern in both places. i'm pretty sure that when i removed the anchors it started failing on the JS-side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good at regular expressions but would this work?

```
^.{0,100}\n?(.{0,100}\n)?.{0,100}?$
```

Again I'm still new to reg exp, so if there is an error(which is likely) please tell me.

Comment: i think that requires a newline to be present if characters are present? just meaning it looks like the `\n` is part of the optional string, as opposed to optionally part of the string. thus a single line with no new line would incorrectly fail the match.

Comment: also, i think the `\n` will work in JS, but not java. at least i think i got a java issue until i added the `\r` support. thanks for staying on this. i really appreciate your effort!

Comment: Fixed. Ah, I'm doing it in a fiddle.